# Why is it not possible to post as a guest on some Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion

For example, these sites all allow posting as a guest:

- https://superuser.com/
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/
- https://serverfault.com/
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/
- and many more.

These sites do *not* allow posting as a guest:

- https://stackoverflow.com/
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
- https://askubuntu.com/

Why do they not allow posting as a guest?

Comment: Too much spam and low quality posts. If these were to become problems on other sites, they will also block guest posts.

Comment: Since this is about multiple sites in the Stack Exchange network, shouldn't this be on [meta.se]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow [had a problem with bad questions being asked by unregistered users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it), so registration [was required for people to ask questions there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163). This was expanded to other sites that had enough volume and enough bad hit-and-run askers to justify it.

Other sites haven't had as bad a problem with this, so they're a little more open with the question-asking account requirements.